# AOP not working

Tags: spring-boot, aop, autoproxy

I'm using **Spring Boot 1.4.1** with following starters in gradle file:

```
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')            
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation')     
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')       
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop')
```

I'm trying to use the Spring AOP to implement the logging.

```
@Aspect                                                            
@Component                                                         
public class ServiceLogAspect {                                    
  @Before("execution(* method(..)")                                 
  logentry(JoinPoint j) {                                             
    logger.log("Method Entry");                                        
  }                                                                  
}
```

When I run the application, I'm getting the below exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext 
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
 Error creating bean with name 'embeddedServletContainerCustomizerBeanPostProcessor': BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Must set property 'expression' before attempting to match
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:478) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.registerBeanPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:240) ~[spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:697) ~[spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:526) ~[spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761) ~[spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371) ~[spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:111) ~[spring-boot-test-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98) ~[spring-test-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116) ~[spring-test-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
            ... 25 common frames omitted
        Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Must set property 'expression' before attempting to match
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:372) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1128) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1023) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.findAdvisorBeans(BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.java:92) ~[spring-aop-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findCandidateAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:101) ~[spring-aop-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator.findCandidateAdvisors(AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator.java:85) ~[spring-aop-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.autoproxy.AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.shouldSkip(AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:103) ~[spring-aop-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:249) ~[spring-aop-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:993) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.resolveBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:964) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:472) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
            ... 38 common frames omitted
        Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Must set property 'expression' before attempting to match
            at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.checkReadyToMatch(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:187) ~[spring-aop-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.getClassFilter(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:170) ~[spring-aop-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.canApply(AopUtils.java:220) ~[spring-aop-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.canApply(AopUtils.java:279) ~[spring-aop-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.findAdvisorsThatCanApply(AopUtils.java:311) ~[spring-aop-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findAdvisorsThatCanApply(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:118) ~[spring-aop-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findEligibleAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:88) ~[spring-aop-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.getAdvicesAndAdvisorsForBean(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:69) ~[spring-aop-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:347) ~[spring-aop-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:299) ~[spring-aop-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:422) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
            ... 60 common frames omitted
```

If I run the application without the above **Aspect** everything is working fine.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should get an **error** for your `ServiceLogAspect` code.

Here is a very simple example to add AOP functionality with spring boot, you can take it.

```
package com.example;
// ...... importer
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootAopApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootAopApplication.class, args);
    }
}

@Aspect
@Component
class ServiceLogAspect {
    @Before("execution(* com.example.*.*(..))")                           
    public void log(JoinPoint j) {
        System.out.println("Welcome......" + j.getStaticPart());
    }
}

@RestController
class WelcomeController {
    @RequestMapping(path = "/welcome")
    public String welcome() {
        return "Welcome";
    }
}
```

When you visis the GET - http://localhost:8080/welcome

You will see the console message

```
Welcome......execution(String com.example.WelcomeController.welcome())
```

Comment: Thanks Liping, Still I'm not able to make it work. Can you tell me what is wrong in the following @Before("execution(public * com.example.ISample.*(..))")

Comment: @ss1234 Your pointcut expression looks good, can you upload the error message you encountered, thanks.